# Quick way to zoom in on picture in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Sometimes people will send me screenshots in Word documents and they are too small to see. I can drag them to be bigger but that can be a bit of a pain sometimes depending on the size of the picture and the bounds of the page.

Another option is for me to just save the picture to my desktop and open in another app where I can zoom but that's also a bit more trouble than I'd like.

Wondering is there a better way for me to zoom in on a picture in Word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered simply zooming the view of the document? This will enable zooming up to 500%.

At the bottom right of the window, there is a zoom scale:

[image: Word zoom bar]

Dragging the handle right will zoom in on the document.

If you have a mouse with a wheel, holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and rolling the wheel up will also zoom in.

Comment: I knew there had to be some ridiculously simple solution I was overlooking, lol. Thanks.

Comment: What I really wish was that the context menu had an item that would let you open the file in your default viewer, but this is definitely a good solution.